# How to copy from row X down to the first blank cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet which gets updated daily.

It generates a list, based on the updated data, of everyone that needs to complete a particular task that day. That list changes in length day-by-day.

To accomplish the necessary output, it uses formulas in an "if another cell in this row isn't blank, do..." structure:

```
=IF(LEN(I4)=0),"",<get a name from elsewhere>)
```

This list can be quite long. Rather than require the user to scroll excessively, I would like to provide a "copy to clipboard" button.  Users then paste the rows into another application.

I can copy a list with fixed length, say M4 through M500, to the clipboard.  But let's say that today, the list goes to M286, and tomorrow it's to M117, and so on.  I would like to copy only populated cells.

Here's what I've pieced together from Google:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    firstBlankRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4").End(xlDown).Row + 1

    MsgBox (unusedRow)
    Set xSheet = ActiveSheet
    xSheet.Range("M4:M" & firstBlankRow).Copy

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This finds the last cell with a formula in it. That's not what I'm going for. I want the last cell with a value in it, that value being generated by the formula. In this particular case, "last cell with a value" will always be "cell before the first blank cell". There will be no gaps in the list.

How do I find up to the last cell with a value?

Comment: Use a loop with if? Not elegant but should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Column Excluding Blanks At the Bottom

- To exclude blanks (`=""` or `'`) at the bottom of a column, use the `Find` method with its `LookIn` argument's parameter set to `xlValues`.
- Note that this will fail if the worksheet is filtered or if there are hidden rows or columns.

**Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet1`**

- It is assumed that the command button is on the worksheet (`Me`) to be copied from.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CopyColumnNonBlanks Me.Range("M4")
End Sub
```

**Standard Module, e.g. `Module1`**

- Optionally, you can put it in the sheet module with the first code (not recommended). Then you will need to call it with e.g.

  ```
  Sheet1.CopyColumnNonBlanks(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4"))
  ```

  for another worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumnNonBlanks(ByVal FirstCell As Range)
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count _
            - .Row + 1).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "All cells in the column range are blank.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1).Copy
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I only regret that I have but one upvote to give for this response.  This really is the first VBA thing I've ever done, so I appreciate the clear explanation.  I thought I'd have a couple of follow-up questions, but it makes sense.  Thank you.